# Use equals in if conditions or expressions

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to show something only in case my expression is true. I know that I can't use expressions in DOM anymore but I need a way to **pass an attribute to my expression** and I don't know if it is possible now.

How I can resolve this? I don't want to create a child component just for that line...

```
    <!-- my component ---> 
    <template> 
            ....
            <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
               <div if:true={contact.Level__c == "Primary"}>level={level}><div>
            </template> 
    </temlate>
```

Comment: why don't you do the validation in a get method?

Comment: Because I need to use the level. The level is an attribute in contact, but contact is only defined inside my for, so I can access it directly in my js with a get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, I think the best approach to do that is on the js file do a for on the contact list, and add an extra property with type boolean that check if the Level is Primary.

```
 <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
      <div if:true={contact.isPrimary"}>level={level}><div>
  </template>
```